# OpenShift NodeJS deployment : socket.io index.html port assignment, etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, openshift

I locally wrote a nodeJS app using socket.io and express modules.
I wanted to use openshift for hosting.
So I changed the main .js to server.js which seems to be the index equivalent of the openshift file and changed the server port setting to:

var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000);

as indicated in some posts.
However after git commit, I am still getting:

remote: info: socket.io started
remote: warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES
remote: DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0
remote: 
remote: DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'

and the website doesn't work.

As the app is serving a html file, there are two more places, where the port is mentioned, which sit in the index.html that is served:

header:

```
<script src='//localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

and within javascript for the html file:

```
var socket = io.connect('//localhost:'+process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000);
```

// intial vars and multi list from server
socket.on('clientConfig', onClientConfig);

All files and modules are seemingly uploaded, but the EACCES error still prevails.

I get the feeling that maybe the header link to localhost:3000 might be the skipping point, but I am not sure. Anyone have any idea, what the problem is?
Also, there is no : socket.io/socket.io.js file in the socket.io modules folder, which I find confusing.

Answer (score 8):

I had recently developed a chat client application using socket.io and also had webrtc in it. I was able to deploy the app on openshift by making the following changes into code.

**Client Side**

Keep the include script tag in a relative manner like so

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

While declaring io.connection, change the ip part to point the application to server in this format.

`var socket = io.connect('http://yourapp-domain.rhcloud.com:8000/', {'forceNew':true });`

8000 is for http and 8443 is for https

**Server Side**

The io and the server should both be listening on the same port and the order in which the statements are run should also be given attention.

Step 1: Declare the http server using app. 
( app is obtained from express)

`var express = require('express');var app = express();)
var server = require('http').Server(app);`

Step 2:

Declare io from socket.io and combine it with the server object.
`var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`

Step 3:

Now, allow the server to listen to openshift port and ip.

`server.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP);`

Please pay special attention to the order of the statements you write, it is the order which causes issues.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I was spending 5+ hours trying to find what I was doing wrong reading tons of articles that all lead in a similar direction but just didn't spell it out as clear as you did. I didn't realized that the server wasn't actually listening because I believe socket.io was already doing that!

Answer (score 5):

The server side of your websocket needs to listen on port 8080 on your openshift ip address, the CLIENT side needs to connect to your ws://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8000

Comment: So in the server.js it needs to be 8080 and in the html all is ws://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8000 for socket.io, yes?

Comment: Correct.  You can also use wss://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8443 to use ssl

Comment: Okay I changed server.js to:

Comment: var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);

Comment: index.html:    <script src='wss://area56-multisockettest.rhcloud.com:8443/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>

Comment: and the socket init :     var socket = io.connect('wss://area56-multisockettest.rhcloud.com:8443');

Comment: No good people:   remote: DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
remote: DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/533450f25973ca577c00008c/app-root/runtime/repo' for changes.
remote: info: socket.io started
remote: warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES
remote: DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0
remote: 
remote: DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'

Comment: What type of cartridge are you using? Do you already have a web server running on your gear using port 8080?

Comment: Openshift standard nodejs-0.6 + modules thats all

Comment: You need to also bind to your OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP, along with the port, check out this example: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example/blob/master/server.js

Comment: Replaced this: //var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(port);
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen( port, ipaddress, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
}); And the code is running now it seems, however it doesn't execute everything. What's the easiest way seeing the live console.log output?

Answer (score 2):

I have a few notes on how to use WebSockets here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/10-reasons-openshift-is-the-best-place-to-host-your-nodejs-app#websockets

You don't need any additional server-side changes [after adapting your code to take advantage of environment variables (when available)](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps#env_vars)

OpenShift's routing layer exposes your application on several externally-accessible ports: 80, 443, 8000, 8443.

Ports 8000 and 8443 are both capable of handling websocket connection upgrades.  We're hoping to add support for WebSocket connections over ports 80 and 443 soon.

Comment: Okay that is rather confused me, I am still trying to test on teh first answer.

Comment: If you look above I am not using a particular IP on the server side to start the server. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes. Also, "process.env" will only be in scope for your server-side code.  If you want to access that information from client-side javascript, you'll need to establish another way to reference it.

Comment: I thought as much, having the main code running, but I think the relative .js references to other scripts is broken in the index.html. This works fine on my local server, why broken in openshift? Sooo many differences....

Comment: I added 8080 for the server.js and the process.env. On the client side (index.html and socket.js, I added the ws://  xxx:8000 domain location.

Comment: DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Tue, 29 Jul 2014 13:51:04 GMT express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement at server.js:11:5
info: socket.io started
warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Tue, 29 Jul 2014 13:51:06 GMT express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement at server.js:11:5
info: socket.io started
warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES

Comment: ==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
DEBUG:   program 'server.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/53d6ce2f5973caa52c000023/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/53d6ce2f5973caa52c000023/app-root/data/.nodewatch' for changes.
>PORT>8080>IP>127.3.72.1
info: socket.io started
DEBUG: Sending SIGTERM to child...